# Problem with SQLite database in Qt SDK 1.0.2

Tags: qt, sqlite

Hi I have a problem with SqlLite database. Here is my code:

```
void incomeDialog::on_add_pushButton_clicked()
{
int a = ui->income_lineEdit->text().toInt();
int b = ui->other_lineEdit->text().toInt();
int c = (a+b);

db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("money.db");
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.exec("create table Income"
           "(Month TEXT, Payment NUMBER, Other NUMBER, Together NUMBER)");
query.prepare("INSERT INTO Income values (?,?,?,?)");

query.addBindValue(ui->comboBox->currentText());
query.addBindValue(ui->income_lineEdit->text().toInt());
query.addBindValue(ui->other_lineEdit->text().toInt());
query.addBindValue(c);
query.exec();
}
```

I use qt sdk 1.0.2. After building shows errors:

Undefined reference to 'QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QString const&, QString const&)...

all errors is similar (Undefined reference to 'QSqlDatabase::

Do you have any idea how to repair it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `QT += sql` in your project `.pro` file.

Comment: I have it. If i have this in .pro shows error: :: error: [\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\release\gcce\udeb\mon.exe] Error 1.   I debug on symbian device

Comment: That error tells me nothing, update your answer with the full error log.

Comment: only this one error was shown. Also one warning is shown: In function 'QList<QString>::detach_helper_grow(int,int)':

Comment: I added QT += sql to .pro file in this form. Previously I added in QT       += core gui\
 sql